# NVCC ptas=-v output

Tags: cuda

a I compiled my program with "nvcc -ccbin=icpc source/* -Iinclude -arch=sm_35 --ptxas-options=-v
". Output is below:

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : 450 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z21process_full_instancePiPViS1_S_' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z21process_full_instancePiPViS1_S_
    408 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 174 registers, 9748 bytes smem, 352 bytes cmem[0]
```

I think gmem refers to global memory, but why the first line and third line have different values (0 vs 450) for geme?

smem is shared memory, how about cmem?

Is the memory usage for a block or a SM (stream processor)? Blocks are dynamically assigned to SM. Can we infer how many blocks will concurrently run on a SM?

My GPU is K20.

Comment: Are you using a global variable in your kernel? Also, does your kernel yield the same result every time you launch it?

Comment: My kernel does not use __global__ variables. But there are variables in global memory from cudaMalloc. It seems that pxtas does not report memory usage from those variables.

Comment: It is your own kernel or are you using an external library (e.g. cublas)?

Comment: The program was developed by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> smem is shared memory, how about cmem?

- **cmem** stands for constant memory
- **gmem** stands for global memory
- **smem** stands for shared memory
- **lmem** stands for local memory
- **stack frame** is part of local memory
- **spill loads** and **store** use part of the stack frame

> Is the memory usage for a block or a SM (stream processor)?

No, the number of registers is per thread while the shared memory is per block.

> Can we infer how many blocks will concurrently run on a SM?

No. Since you can't determine the number of threads per block you cannot calculate the resources each block requires.

Comment: From my observation, it seems that the memory usage is for a block. In my example, a block uses about 9k shared memory. Since k20 have up to 48k shared memory, 5 blocks can be run concurrently on the same stream processor.

Comment: In my mind, you need to know the number of registers per thread and the number of threads per block in order to determine the number of blocks that fill on a SM. Shared memory per block its only one part of the equation.

Comment: In my program, a block has 32 threads. Since each threads use 174 registers, then a block uses around 5500 registers?

Comment: Yes. Then, you divide the available number of registers per block between 5568 (registers per block) and the available shared memory per thread, get the minimum number among these two numbers and you'll have the number of blocks per SM.

Comment: For CC3.5 the register allocation granularity is 8 registers to each threads will use 176 registers. 176 * 32 = 5632. This is insufficient to fit 3 warps per warp scheduler so you will be limited to 8 warps. If shared memory usage is 9K then shared memory per block is the limiter.

Comment: Greg, can you give more details on the limit for warps per warp scheduler? For example, why is there a limit on warps per warp scheduler? What is the relationship between limit on warps per warp and the number of blocks running concurrently on a SM?